# For G and H groups, show that (G×{e})◃(G×H), then show that the quotient (G×H)/(G×{e}) is isomorphic to H.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Have no idea where to start :( I think the solution will have to be something like showing that the group (G x {e}) is normal by doing something with left cosets, and isomorphism wouldn't be too hard to check after that part, but I'm really stuck

Comment: Showing that $G\times \{e\}$ is a normal subgroup is a pure calculational matter. Proving the isomorphism can be done by using the first isomorphism theorem if you choose the surjective map $G\times H \to H,\ (g,h) \mapsto h$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map from $G\times H$ to $H$ given by $(g,h)\mapsto h$. Prove it's a group homomorphism; then note that its kernel is $G\times\{e\}$; then use the theorems that say the kernel of a group homomorphism is a normal subgroup, and the image is isomorphic to the quotient.

Comment: Thanks! If I could check really quick with you, in demonstrating that you have a group isomorphism, you would say that f((g1, h1) * (g2, h2)) = h1 * h2 = f(g1, h1) * f(g2, h2), or something similar, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's right.